# Childwindow inside MainWindow shows for a second then disappears

Tags: c++, winapi

I have MainWindow instance and inside I want to create a bunch of child windows which are the instance of GemWindow Class I do so by

```
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < win.GetcGem(); i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < win.GetcGem(); j++)
        {
            if (!win.Gems[i][j].Create(L"gem", WS_CHILDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, NULL, 0, 0, 80, 80, win.Window(), NULL))
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

but child windows show for a second (at least on my machine) then they disappear I checked using spy++ and there are windows as children of my MainWindow but they are not displayed.
I couldn't find any solid reason for it to erase them.

Thanks if you take time to help

Comment: You create them all on top of each other. Is that intentional?

Comment: @CherryDT Yes, I did so to test

Comment: Is the parent window created using the [WS_CLIPCHILDREN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) window style? Either way, the question cannot be answer with the information provided. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, the parent has the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` window style. I will try to create an example until that time here is [project repository](https://github.com/sbecerek/BeJeweled)

Comment: The child windows show just fine. They just happen to have the same color as the parent. What did you expect to observe?

Comment: @IInspectable I want to paint them and to do so have the line `wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(125, 125, 125));` in `Create()` method of GemWindow class. Should I use `SetWindowLongPtr()` instead?

Comment: Painting is done in response to a `WM_PAINT` message. [Using the WM_PAINT Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/using-the-wm-paint-message) explains how the system works.

Comment: Your problem cannot be reproduced after I tried it, and the case link you provided is no longer valid. So I hope you can provide a sample of the recurring problem so that we can solve the problem for you.Thanks.

Comment: @ZhuSong Problem is that I want to paint the background of the Window without using GDI, unlike @IInspectable's suggestion. As I said, setting `wc.hbrBackground` on GemWindows did not work. What I examined is that they take the color for a while then color themselves to the color of the MainWindow. I wonder if there is a way to change the background color of a window without handling the `WM_PAINT` message, and the link is accessible once again, I am going to keep it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the background color through the [`SetClassLong`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclasslonga) function without processing the `WM_PAINT` message.

Only need to modify the code as:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < GetcGem(); i++)
{
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < GetcGem(); j++)
    {
        if (Gems[i][j].Create(L"gem", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, NULL, 5 + i * GetsGem().cx + i * 5, 5 + j * GetsGem().cy + j * 5, GetsGem().cx, GetsGem().cy, Window(), NULL))
        {
            HBRUSH hbrush = CreateSolidBrush(0X7d7d7d);//rgb hexadecimal
            HBRUSH hOldBrush = (HBRUSH)SetClassLongPtr(Gems[i][j].Window(), GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG_PTR)hbrush);
            DeleteObject(hOldBrush);
            InvalidateRect(Gems[i][j].Window(), NULL, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    
}
```